# Automated testing for android purchase flow

Tags: android, automated-tests

I'm trying to create some automated tests for all branches of my purchase flow, so that my test code initiates and cancels purchases without me having to interact with the device at all. I've tried using the static responses, but I'm still encountering a blank Google Play purchase confirmation pop-up on the device. It looks like the shape of the usually pop-up where you choose what sort of test card to use, but it's just an outline with no buttons. Not sure if the static responses are intended for later stages of development, but they don't seem to meet my needs. Is there a simple testing framework or API out there that can enable me to test my full purchase flow without interacting with the device? Thanks!